# How to show google map after click on search button in same activity in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to call Map.java class to show Google Map after click on button. I used an onClickListener. Then I used an Intent to start an activity. For this class, I create a layout and inside, I declare  a Fragment in flow Layout.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then I declare the permissions inside my manifest as follows:

```
// Permission and Uses-features
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="I have a key which provide by Google " />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

But on Emulator can't load this and gives me some following error:

> ```
> 1--- "unfortunately stopped application" to load .
> 2--- "could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB"
> 3---  "Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer".
> 4---  " Failed to create Context 0x3005"
> ```

Comment: try to run your app in real physical device

Answer (score 0):

Change xml code like this:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If you want to display map you have to run the application with real physical device instead of Emulator

Comment: Without device is possible or not.

Comment: without device, you can get maps in a tile view in emulator and doesnot dynamically get GPS service also.

Comment: i have wifi connection then

Answer (score 0):

Make the fragment android:visibility as GONE and the button on click set visibility as Visible 
`<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"`
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        `android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />`

Answer (score 0):

You change XML code

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"></fragment>
```

In manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

You should declare your activity in manifest.

In your activity class

```
gMap =((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

run your project in real device.